# Prepend AD User description with PS - Duplicate Update with ForEach

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I've seen many code examples where Get-ADUser can be used to *append* a description with the following code:

```
get-aduser username -Properties Description | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $_ -Description "$($_.Description) Some more stuff" }
```

I had thought I could simply invert the order of the code in order to prepend, like so:

```
get-aduser username -properties Description | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $_ -Description "Stuff To Use - $($_.Description)"}
```

The output then becomes:

```
"Stuff To Use - Stuff To Use"
```

In essence, whatever is there to start with is wiped out completely and replaced with a doubled up result of the intended goal.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The code is good. Did you run it twice? Reset the description, run the code, then refresh ADUC and check.

Comment: What the... I am so confused now HAH! I made zero changes, hit the can, came back, reran like you suggested... and now it works just fine? What on earth.

Is it because it's a monday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is good and it likely ran twice accidentally.

Reset the description, run the code, then refresh Active Directory Users and Computers and recheck.